# VBA sin() and cos() trouble

Tags: excel, vba, trigonometry

Im trying to make some VBA form and to calculate some simple values but I dont understand why VBA dosen't recognize Sin() and Cos() functions. For example: I wrote int() and VBA transformed it into Int(), but it doesn't do the same with sin and cos. 
Moreover, after I'm trying to compile my code

```
    Private Sub btn_exit_Click()
    Unload laborator_2
End Sub

Private Sub btn_start_Click()
    today.Caption = Date
    rnb_val.Caption = Int(Rnd * 90 + 1)
    sqrt_val.Caption = Sqr(rnb_val.Caption)
    si_val.Caption = sin(rnb_val.Caption * 3.14159 / 180)
    co_val.Caption = rnb_val.Caption * 3.1459 / 180
End Sub
```

I got this message:

```
Run-time error "424" Object required
```

[image]

Im new in VBA, so sorry if I didn't write all details. Thank you.

Comment: In Editor's Immediate window (ctrl+G) type `?sin(1)` and hit return, do you get a result? if not how about `?math.sin(1)`

Comment: One thing you can be sure of, it is not the sin function. What kind of controls are you referring to? Textboxes? Labels? And the error is in the sin line?

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.Sin`

Comment: P.s. it looks like you have a typo on the last line. Did you mean `3.1459` or `3.14159`?

Comment: you know `nb_val.Caption` is text and needs to be converted to a floating point number. Also use a single global for pi, as in `Public Const PI As Double = 3.14159265358979`

Comment: @Kapol - there is no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

sin & cos are not functions that are built into vba. They are, however, built into excel and can be accessed through the $WorksheetFunction$ object of vba as $WorksheetFunction.Sin$ and $WorksheetFunction.Cos$. Any functions that you can use in a spreadsheet are accessible this way.

Comment: sin/cos *are* built into VBA, they are part of the Math namespace along with round(), log() etc

Answer (score 0):

Check the names that you have given to your labels on the form - they must match exactly the names in the code. I got the same error by naming the si_val label sival instead.