# How to make a Cosd Function with VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2011

I need to make a function that finds Cosine in Degrees. I am on Mac-OS Excel 2011

```
Function cosd(d)
    deg = (d * 3.14159265358979) / 180    
    cosd = WorksheetFunction.Cos(deg)
End Function
```

It still does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA sin() and cos() trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971654/vba-sin-and-cos-trouble)

Comment: On later versions of Excel there is a built-in `WorksheetFunction.Cosd()`

Comment: If there is a native worksheetfunction with the same name as your function, that will probably explain the `#NAME`-error too. Otherwise I'm not sure what could be the reason for it. Maybe the wrong kind of data in the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close the only trouble with your function (well, besides that not declaring your variables is bad practice) is that `Cos` isn't a VBA function. Change your function to

```
Function cosd(d As Double) As Double
  cosd = Application.WorksheetFunction.Cos((d * Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi) / 180#)
End Function
```

and it should work just fine.

Comment: It says "error:expected end of statement". I have pulled all my hair over this?!

Comment: Whoops, forgot to add in a parantheses at the start of the statement, fixed now @WaleedKAl-Shaikhli

Comment: Why not use the bult-in `Cos()` function defined in VBA?

Comment: I cant get it to work. When I type "cosd(90)" in a cell the output is "#NAME?"

Comment: @ja72 According to the original question, using the native `COS`-function didn't work. He's changed it now, so I can't check it again to see if there were any other problems, but I didn't see anything obvious. Could it possibly be that the `COS`-function needs to be preceded by `Math.`? Some googling seems to indicate this, but I am not at my work computer atm, so I can't check.